# Looking up values in multiple tables with multiple joins

Tags: sql-server

How would you do a Select statement to lookup a value in a table and then use that value to lookup another value in another table which is then used to lookup a third value in a third table? I cannot do a join from my initial table as there is no common matching field to do the join on.
In my initial table I have an Instr_Id value which is the only possible way to eventually get the Legal_Id value but the table where the Legal_Id is stored does not have an Instr_Id value. In order to do this I need to look up multiple values from 2 other tables to eventually get to the INSTR_ID value.

Example:

I use INSTR_ID in tbl.ABC and join to INSTR_ID in tbl.DEF in order to get the Fin_Enty_Name value in tbl.DEF I then need to use this Fin_Enty_Name value to join to tbl.GHI to get the Fin_Enty_Id . I finally then need to use this Fin_Enty_Id to look up the LEGAL_ID in tbl.JKL so that I can show the LEGAL_ID for each INSTR_ID in my Select query results.

```
select 
a.INSTR_ID, 
d.LEGAL_IT 
from tbl.ABC as A 
Inner join tbl.DEF as B on A.INSTR_ID = B.INSTR_ID
```

[image: See table info here]

Comment: Images of data isn't helpful to those you're asking for help from; we can consume it and therefore can't use it. Please supply your data as tabular formatted `text`, or as DDL and DML statement. Along with your well formatted sample data, can you show us the expected results you are after as well please, and show us what you've tried to get to that end result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks pretty much straight forward:

```
select a.instr_id, d.legal_id
from   tbl.abc a
join   tbl.def b
on     a.instr_id = b.instr_id
join   tbl.ghi c
on     b.fin_enty_name = c.fin_enty_name
join   tbl.jkl d
on     c.fin_enty_id = d.fin_enty_id
```